# Why am I having so much trouble submitting my app to Apple?

Tags: ios, xcode8.2, ios10.2

This is my first time trying to submit an app to Apple, and I'm having a bunch of issues. I'm pretty sure I've generated all my certificates, AppID's, etc... I've been running the app on my phone just fine, then all of a sudden I started getting errors submitting. My first error was this:

[image]

But as you can see, the Bundle ID's are the same:

The ID in Xcode:

[image]

And the ID in iTunes Connect:

[image]

So I tried changing the Bundle ID, and made sure the Bundle ID's were the same across iTunes connect, Xcode, etc. I started out the project with a different name. Should I just start a new project with consistent naming?

Should the Bundle Identifier in Info read com.Kaen.M01eskin ?

[image]

It doesn't work with Application Loader either:

[image]

Comment: When I was submitting my first app, I had lots of trouble and headaches too! You are not alone! It turned out that my provisioned profile was wrong in my XCode. I had to choose the profile manually rather than rely on XCode to choose the profile automatically. Good luck!

Comment: How do you do that? I edited my question, so maybe you'll have some new insight! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere the bundle identifier is getting `M01eskin---`prepended to it. As you can see in the dialog. I would check in your `info.plist` if perhaps there is something in `Bundle identifier` before the `$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)`.

You could try hard coding it there and see if that resolves your problems.

Or try looking in your build settings for the target under `Product Bundle Identifier` and check there as well.

Comment: I just added a screenshot to the bottom of my question. Should the Bundle Identifier in Info match the others?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure bundle id is same on your application & [iTunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com).

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Application Loader utility instead of the Archive upload to the App Store. It's available in the menu under Xcode... Open Developer Tool... Application Loader.  You still have to create an Archive first; main difference is that you have to pick out your Archive via a Finder interface. Plus, you can get an active timeline for all the tasks, with current task and elapsed times.

Comment: I just tried it. It doesn't work. I updated my question with a screenshot of what happened.